# how to install android studio completely?

Tags: android, kvm-virtualization, android-studio, android-sdk

Hello every one I want to install android studio  and first I run the .sh file by this command `./studio.sh` and after that I try to install it but at first I have this problem[image]

but the thing is that I already have java JDK 7 
and after this when I chose next to install it it just goes to the were that it shows the summery of chosen items and I find some errors in terminal[image]

how you see it has been repeated a couple of times and after that I got this massage and android studio doesn,t install at at all.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

it might be a temporary problem with broken package.

Download Android Studio from:  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.0.12/android-studio-ide-145.3276617-linux.zip

Download manually Android-sdk from: https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

Unpack and run the intallation steps, but instead of downloading whole SDK choose thedirectory to  existing and unpacked.